# How to add active navigation based on URL in angular?

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-directive, routerlink, routerlinkactive

**Here is my problem--**
I have created a navbar with RouterLink directive and I wanted my navigation link to be active to the current URL path so I am using RouterLinkActive directive. But my CSS active class is not updating to any URL path. I don't know why. Is there any solution to this problem ?

**Here is my code**

Navigation bar: **app.component.html**

```
<nav class="header-links">
      <img src="../assets/images/logo.png" alt="" class="logo">
      <a routerLink="/contact" routerLinkActive="active" style="margin-right: 35px;">Contact us</a>
      <a routerLink="/product" routerLinkActive="active">Our Product</a>
      <a routerLink="/about" routerLinkActive="active">About us</a>
      <a routerLink="/home" routerLinkActive="active">Home</a> 
</nav>
```

CSS to be apply : **app.component.css**

```
.active {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Routing Paths: **app.routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AboutComponent } from './component/about/about.component';
import { ContactComponent } from './component/contact/contact.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './component/home/home.component';
import { ProductComponent } from './component/product/product.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {path:'', redirectTo:'home', pathMatch:'full'},
  {path:'home', component: HomeComponent},
  {path:'about', component: AboutComponent},
  {path:'product', component: ProductComponent},
  {path:'contact', component: ContactComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { relativeLinkResolution: 'legacy' })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

I tried *[routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}"* still nothing changes and also I tried to set my active css class to be global still nothing. Am I missing anything here ?

Answer (score 1):

**Since no response I found myself an answer by using parent class to navigate to the active class**

```
.header-links .active {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: underline;
 }
```

Posting this answer, If it might helps anyone in the future.